# Integer expression

Tags: diophantine-equations, fractions, integers

Expression $$\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{a+c}+\frac{c}{a+b}$$
takes an integer value $2$ when $a=t, b=t, c=3t$. Are there any other integer values of variables for integer value of expression?

Comment: For example, $\;a=b=1,\,c=0\;$ ...and again you get $\;2\;$ in the sum. :)

Comment: what about value 4 for expression?

Comment: You might be interested to read [This](https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-find-the-positive-integer-solutions-to-frac-x-y%2Bz-%2B-frac-y-z%2Bx-%2B-frac-z-x%2By-4/answer/Alon-Amit)

Comment: thanks. but only 4 and 896 in this article. I don't understand only 2, 4 and 896 can be obtained?

Comment: [Another link](http://ami.ektf.hu/uploads/papers/finalpdf/AMI_43_from29to41.pdf). Warning: it contains a lot of numbers and it is easy to get confused. Enjoy =]

Comment: If you want the sum to equal $\;4\;$ you'll need 80-digit numbers of so...and that only to get **the smallest** solution! Much harder, though: you'll have to understand and know elliptic curves in order to understand how those solutions were obtained.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/264754/solution-to-a-diophantine-equation/275193#275193

Answer (score 1):

For example, take  $$(t,t,-2t)$$ for $t\neq0$.

$a+b+c=0$ is valid

Comment: other solutions are (t,t,-5t), (2t,t,-3t), (3t,5t,-5t), (-7t,9t,19t), (8t,7t,-5t) but more intresting question is positive integer values a,b,c making the whole expression intereger. And this answer @Galc127 gave me in his comments.

Comment: Yes, it's indeed very interesting. Thank you!